# Can we use gcc optimization flags over mpicc?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, mpi, compiler-optimization, openmpi

I tried compiling MPI programs with `mpicc` by passing `-O1` `-O2` `-O3` etc optimization flags. I would like to know whether optimization flags really work with `mpicc` and also wether `mpicc` supports all the optimization flags of `gcc` compiler.

Comment: The optimization flags for `gcc` are `-O1`, `-O2`, etc. - the letter 'o' needs to be a capital O...

Answer (score 4):

`mpicc`, `mpic++`, `mpif90`, `mpif77`, etc. are all just wrappers around the actual system compiler. Any option that the wrapper does not recognise as its own gets passed to the actual compiler. You can see what is being invoked behind the scenes by calling `mpicc` with the `-showme` option:

```
$ mpicc -showme
gcc ... <lots of options> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

absolutely. **All** flags passed to `mpicc`, `mpic++` and the likes are passed to the "original" compiler.